# How to change background image change on hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to hover over div id-"RollOver1" and be able to change the background to a different image from the main one. Only pasted the HTML for the rollover div cant use jscript so is there a way in HTML or ....?

```
<div id="RollOver1" style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;left:152px;top:397px;width:183px;height:183px;z-index:4">
<a href="./car.html">
<img class="hover" alt="" src="images/Enter_02.jpg" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 183px; height: 183px; display: block;">
<span style="display: none;"><img alt="" src="images/index_01.jpg" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:183px;height:183px"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you [search "HTML Hover"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=html%20hover) in Google your answer is first in the list (albeit provided by W3Schools)

Comment: why people ask such kind of question on stackoverflow?..google it.

Comment: well actualy we ask these questions because what we tried we didnt understand hence ask the question again and hope for another answer that you can understand.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:hover` pseudo class:

```
#RollOver1 {
   background: url('img1.png');
}

#RollOver1:hover {
   background: url('img2.png');
}
```

But you will usually see "glich" between changes of images, because second image will take some time to be loaded.
To avoid that, use image sprite. Put both images (normal and hover) to single image and than use css `background-position`

```
#RollOver1 {
    background: url('sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#RollOver1:hover {
     background-position: -80px -90px;
}
```

It will be more efficient way to load small images (like buttons, icons and so on).
[Check this link](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following code:

```
#RollOver1 {
   background:url(INITIAL_BACKGROUND);//here use the url of the background you want when is NOT on hover
}
#RollOver1:hover {
   background:url(BACKGROUND_ON_HOVER);//here use the url of the bg you want when is on hover
}
```

Comment: since i already have an initial background image can i do the below instead
#RollOver1 a:hover {
backgroundimage: url(images/splash-spring_mercedes.jpg);
}

Answer (score 0):

use the css pseudo class `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can try

```
    $(document).on("mouseover", "#RollOver1", function(e) {
$(this).css("background", "url(sampleImage.png) no-repeat");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below styles

```
.RollOver1:hover {
   background-image: url('paper.gif');
}
```